# Can I run Docker on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise)?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I’m looking to implement a PoC of [Docker](https://www.docker.com) for a project, but only have machines available that run Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise). I’m not sure the kernel version is up-to-date enough to run Docker.

What problems if any do you anticipate me seeing trying to use these machines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven’t used Docker, but it seems like you can. You just need to make sure that [the Linux Kernel is in the 3.8 range—or higher—as explained here](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/#ubuntu-precise-1204-lts-64-bit):

> Due to a bug in LXC, Docker works best on the 3.8 kernel. Precise
>   comes with a 3.2 kernel, so we need to upgrade it. The kernel you'll
>   install when following these steps comes with AUFS built in. We also
>   include the generic headers to enable packages that depend on them,
>   like ZFS and the VirtualBox guest additions. If you didn't install the
>   headers for your "precise" kernel, then you can skip these headers for
>   the "raring" kernel. But it is safer to include them if you're not
>   sure.

That might sound daunting, but the thing you need to know is Ubuntu 12.04 is an LTS (Long Term Service) release. Meaning Canonical makes sure to provide improved kernel support from now— and in the case of Ubuntu 12.04 until Spring 2017—via [LTS Enablement Stacks as explained here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack):

> The Ubuntu LTS enablement stacks provide newer kernel and X support
>   for existing LTS releases. These can be installed manually, or are
>   automatically shipped if installing from 12.04.2/14.04.2 and newer
>   release media.

So if the Ubuntu 12.04 machine you are working on has not had the kernel upgraded, you need to ensure the system kernel is up to date running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty
```

Once that’s done, just reboot it and the kernel will be upgraded and good to go. I’ve done this myself on multiple Ubuntu 12.04 servers without incident.

For example, I just checked the Linux kernel version on an Ubuntu 12.04 server I manage via `uname -r` and this is the response I get:

```
3.13.0-45-generic
```

So that server’s kernel is in the 3.13 range—well past 3.2 and even 3.8—so it is clearly ready for Docker use if desired.

And FWIW, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is one most common releases out there right now; 13.10, 14.04 and 16.04 are good but just “odd” enough for most production environments that admins prefer to keep things at Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for now. Meaning you are not using an “odd duck” setup; just one that is not as cutting edge as an overall release but is stable, supported and fully capable of supporting tasks that require a newer kernel setup.